# Are optionals really necessary in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, option-type

From what I understand, Swift was presented as an upgrade from Objective-C for developers to use in their applications. One new concept that went with it is the concept of "optional variables," or any sort of variable that may hold nothing.

In Objective-C, this was almost implicit. You could assign a value of `nil` to many kinds of variables, but, in Swift, the variable **has to be an optional.**

For instance, this sort of statement is **completely okay** in Objective-C:

```
SKNode *someNode = [SKNode new];
// some methods appear that may change the value of "someNode."
// they are right here. These "methods" might leave "someNode"
// equal to "nil". If not, they might set "someNode" to a node
// equal to a node that exists already.

// check if it's nil.
if (someNode == nil) {
    // code to run if it exists
}
else {
    // code to run if it doesn't exist
}
```

And in Swift, this code:

```
var node = SKNode.new()
// this "node" is created/used like "someNode" is used above.
if node != nil {
     // code that will run if node exists
}
else {
     // code to run if node doesn't exist
}
```

will give the error:

> `Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SKNode' and 'nil'`

However, change the Swift initialization of `node` to this, and you'll be gold, **because you're *explicitly* defining `node` as an optional.**

```
var node : SKNode? = SKNode.new()
```

May I add, this doesn't work either:

```
var node = SKNode?.new()
```

Giving the error:

> `'SKNode?.Type' does not have a member named 'new'`

**Why does the node have to be *explicitly* defined as an optional?**

Comment: As an aside, the "standard" practice with swift is to say something like: `if let n = node { } else { }`. That way you can access your unwrapped variable easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `var node : SKNode? = SKNode.new()`, `node` has to be *explicitly* defined as an optional because `SKNode.new()` will **never** return nil.

The goal of types in Swift is to guarantee that once a variable is defined, its type will never change, and the variable will always have valid data.  Defining a variable as an optional (`SKNode?`) means the variable is an `Optional<SKNode>` which is **NOT** equivalent to `SKNode` (hence `'SKNode?.Type' does not have a member named 'new'`)

The error `Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SKNode' and 'nil'` that you are receiving is cause because you are trying to check if a non-optional value is `Optional.None` (or `nil`), which is a completely unnecessary (and impossible) check in the language.

Comment: I see, it's for type safety! That'll make it so I can't, for example, do something completely stupid that'll either break the compiler or the OS, i.e. try to use an `int` as a `long`.

Comment: That's correct. Swift does something similar for type casting; in obj-c you could do something like `int someInt = (int)someFloat`, however in Swift you do `someInt = Int(someFloat)` rather than `someInt = someFloat as Int` since Floats and Ints are independent.

Comment: That's pretty neat! It just seems to me that the positions of the parentheses are flipped.